# Typescript error when value can be function or null

Tags: typescript

I have a type set up as follows

```
type StateProps = { 
    isPending: boolean,
    asyncFn: (...args: any[]) => void | null
}
```

I then create an initialState variable which has null for asyncFn

```
let initialState = {
    isPending: false,
    asyncFn: null
}
```

Then later in I use it in a react reducer as follows.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {...initialState})
```

but it produces the following error

**Type 'null' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => void | null'**

I thought that my asyncFn could be a function (with any number of args) or null if no function is supplied, as indicated by the single pipe symbol. Have I misunderstood this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type:

```
(...args: any[]) => void | null
```

is not

```
((...args: any[]) => void) | null
```

but

```
(...args: any[]) => (void | null)
```

That is, it's the type for a function which either returns `null` or `void`.

I'd put `null` in the first position instead, to make it clear:

```
asyncFn: null | (...args: any[]) => void
```

(or make the property optional: `asyncFn?: (...args: any[]) => void`)

To be type-safe, also consider using `unknown` instead of `any`.

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious now that the second set of parentheses are needed.